# Symfony 4 form with data mapper and event POST_SUBMIT problem

Tags: forms, symfony, events, mapper

I have a problem with submit form with data mapper. I defined `POST_SUBMIT` event.

I seem to me that after this event as if the form has no fields.

I receive error:

> Uncaught PHP Exception ErrorException: "Notice: Undefined index: name" at D:\wamp\www\symfony\src\Form\Type\Admin\Menu\MenuForm.php line 152.

Below code:

https://gist.github.com/pietrach/1af943a9b782e1a6c2289ac27abae04e?fbclid=IwAR0SezwrXtIeplsW2oTs69ITyZUDkRo4eR7qmPJ050hXXCWP5Ad6fxkKLEI

Comment: You [cannot add elements](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#c-the-formevents-post-submit-event) after submit (corresponding to your lines 197/201).

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms. There is an example with this. I added POST_SUBMIT to field, not form.

Comment: Does the `MenuSection` entity have `name` field?

Comment: I've solved the problem. When listeners are added to single fields then these fields are sent only to mapper. I added checking if the form field exist

https://gist.github.com/pietrach/1af943a9b782e1a6c2289ac27abae04e

Comment: @JakubMatczak yes, `MenuSection` entity have `name` field